# What can websites learn about me when I disable cookies?

Tags: cookies

I run Google Chrome with Ghostery, Privacy Badger, AdBlock and cookies disabled. If, theoretically, Ghostery is blocking all the trackers, AdBlock blocks ads, and I don't accept cookies, what can the sites I visit learn about me? Can they still track my IPs, my location,...

Comment: You've asked three unrelated questions. This is bad practice on Stackexchange. We want questions which can be answered separately, so I edited them out. You are free to ask the two remaining questions again. The text you wrote is still in your answer and can be copy- and pasted when you click on `edit`. However, the questions would be more appropriate on https://superuser.com because the first one has nothing at all to do with security and the second is about the usability, not about the security aspects.

Answer (score 1):

A great deal amount you can be learned, and correlated without using cookies or your IP address.

Cookies serve the purpose of tracking specifically *you*. However other methods of tracking have been found to be 99.1% accurate  in tracking *you* by using other unique characteristics of your browser/session/machine. Some of the unique identifiers are your user-agent, your screen size/density, your java/flash version etc. Read the white paper [here](https://panopticlick.eff.org/browser-uniqueness.pdf) (or at least the abstract for an over view of their findings).

You can see the unique characteristics that can be pulled to represent *you* without the need of a cookie on the main site of that white paper [here](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).

Comment: Thanks thats very usefull info, still that kind of info is not really really personall, you can know my screen size if i have cookies enabled or no, but can them track my ip, know where exactly and when i visited a website, and how could someone use that info to get to my physical location?

Comment: @Vitor Yes, they can certainly track your IP. It is impossible to establish TCP connections without providing some kind of IP address. Because your browser fingerprint is probably unique (or close to unique), they can also know exactly and when you visit a website if they want to. Physical location is harder to say - usually they can determine your location using your IP address to within 30 miles or so, but only your ISP can link your IP to an exact  address. ISPs usually provide this info only when they receive a court order.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you really want to know what someone can learn from your browser. set up an "experiment". a small Apache server with a simple webpage and ALL logging on. attach a local piwik installation to it. and "visit" your own site.. you will be surprised what things get send over the wire.

this type of knowledge is often best when acquired for one self. instead of being "told" by anyone.